# Flutter drag and drop inside UI in desktop application

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, desktop-application

Talking about a **desktop application** now, not mobile or web.

Is it any widget in `Flutter` that will allow, for example, drag a folder, drop it in the application UI, and the app will read for example the path to that file or folder?

I have been reading about `Draggable` and `DragTarget` in `Flutter`, but i do think they are used for that purpose.

**NOTE:** it might not exist a widget for that purpose, so a strategy on how to do that in Flutter will also be appreciated.

Comment: you might want to follow this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30719 and i am pretty much sure we have to wait for an year at least for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about dragging from outside the application, it's not currently supported; [Flutter #30719](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30719) would be the issue to watch/upvote.

Depending on the specific platform you might be able to implement it with a plugin in the short term (if you are familiar with native development on that platform), but that would likely be more work than contributing an implementation to Flutter itself.

Comment: mmm ok too bad...yes this is exactly what i am asking for...from outside to the app...ok but good to know. Thanks.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_drop for desktop

Answer (score 5):

Flutter has a dependency to support such behavior now. Check this link
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_drop

Comment: Do you maybe know of there's plans for OLE support? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/drag-and-drop-ole?view=msvc-170